# How get DNS SRV records using Strophe JS?

Tags: javascript, dns, xmpp, strophe

How get DNS SRV records using Strophe JS? I need them to make custom authentication validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a server component to find it for you. I do not think browser exposes an API for that. You can write a node.js server-side component for example, using https://github.com/dhruvbird/dns-srv

Your Javascript would then send an HTTP query to you server to retrieve the result of the DNS SRV lookup made by your server-side component.